# Angular js input models not accessible inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using this code to view and add peoples in an array.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body>

<h1>People</h1>

<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>

<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**add.html**

```
<h1>Add</h1>

<input type="text" ng-model="new_name" placeholder="Name">
<br />
<input type="text" ng-model="new_age" placeholder="Age">

<br />
<button ng-click="add()">Add</button>

<hr />
<a href="#/">Back</a>
```

**controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl: 'list.html'
        })
        .when('/add',{
            templateUrl: 'add.html',

        });
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.people = [{'name':'Alex', 'age':25}, {'name':'Dan', 'age': 25}];
    $scope.add = function(){
        $scope.people.push({'name':$scope.new_name, 'age':$scope.new_age});
        $location.path("/");
    };
});
```

The problem is, I am not getting data from `ng-model="new_name"` into the controller method `$scope.add = function()`. After pressing add button only blank strings gets pushed into array. However the model and controller working perfectly without routing and ng-view directive. I think its scope related problem. Can any body help me in this.
Thanks.

Comment: What is app directory structure ?

Comment: All files are in the same dir.

Answer (score 1):

Because you should specify the controller for each view. So try doing this:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl: 'list.html',
            controller: 'Ctrl'
        })
        .when('/add',{
            templateUrl: 'add.html',
            controller: 'Ctrl'
        });
});
```

A better solution would be to have a separate controller for each view. Also, have a look at the [$routeProvider documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

Answer (score 1):

Just delete `<div ng-controller="Ctrl">` from index.html and add a controller attribute for your route.

controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl: 'list.html'
        })
        .when('/add',{
            templateUrl: 'add.html',
            controller: 'Ctrl'
        });
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($location,$scope) {
    $scope.people = [{'name':'Alex', 'age':25}, {'name':'Dan', 'age': 25}];
    $scope.add = function(){
        $scope.people.push({'name':$scope.new_name, 'age':$scope.new_age});
        $location.path("/");
    };
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body>

<h1>People</h1>

<div ng-view></div>

<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to wrap your inputs with `<form>` tag with `name=''` attribute.
Next step is to give `name=''` attributes for each `<input>` tag. Look:

```
<form name='myLoginForm'>
    <input name='nick' ng-model='loginFormModel.nick'>
    <input name='password' ng-model='loginFormModel.password'>
</form>
```

In controller:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($location,$scope) {
    $scope.loginFormModel = {}; //now you have whole values from view in this variable, for example nick is available in $scope.loginFormModel.nick
});
```